# ACES color wheel in blender

Tags: color, color-management

Hello is there somebody who uses ACES in blender? I have few questions. First one, how to change color wheel's color space to aces, because default color wheel goes crazy with Aces and i have found in blender documentation, there is something called "rules" and one of the is "color_picker" and i have no idea how to use this rule in order to fix this wheel. https://docs.blender.org/.../render/color_management.html

Second question is more sophisticated, about blender's color space transforms in aces, but maybe later with this one, if someone who uses Aces will come forward.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Utility - sRGB - Texture` instead of `Output - sRGB` can give you a "traditional" look colorwheel.

The RGB numbers displayed in the colorwheel are always in scene linear color space. In ACES workflow, the scene linear space should be ACEScg. (1,0,0) means a pure red in AP1 color space.
However, the **color** displayed in colorwheel UI uses the `color_picking` color space.

Hope [my sample config](https://github.com/Ginurx/Blender-ACES-Config) file helps.